# Limits of the form $\displaylines{\lim_{x\to a} [\varphi (x)]^{\psi (x) } }$

Tags: limits

I'm having a hard time trying to understand rule number 3 on the image below:

[image]

Firstly, I don't get how $\varphi (x)=1+a(x)$. I also don't understand how the exponent $\psi (x)$ changed to $a(x) \psi (x)$. Can somebody explain this to me in simple english please?

Comment: Sinc $\varphi(x)$ is given, in order to have $\varphi(x) = 1 + \alpha(x)$ you define $\alpha(x) = \varphi(x)-1$.  Of course, then the exponent $\alpha(x)\psi(x)$ may be changed to $(\varphi(x)-1)\psi(x)$.  Before that we wrote $\psi(x)$ as $$\psi(x) = \frac{1}{\alpha(x)}\;\alpha(x)\;\psi(x)$$

Comment: But why would we wanna have that?

Comment: @downmath Google 'the exponential function as a limit'

Answer (score 1):

That must be some old math book.

I would guess somewhere earlier, either in a theorem, example, or exercise, it was shown that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (1 + x)^{\frac 1x} = e$$

and that if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = b$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to b} g(x) = c$, and either $c = g(b)$ or $f(x) \ne b$ for $x$ close to $a$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} g(f(x)) = c$.

(Note that the use of "$a(x)$" in the text is a typesetting error. In the limit formula, $\alpha(x)$ is used instead. Since $a$ already has another meaning here,
$\alpha$ is more appropriate.)

The point of setting $\alpha(x) = \varphi(x) - 1$ is that the author is driving towards the form of the limit for $e$. So he rewrites
$$\varphi(x)^{\psi(x)} = (1 + \alpha(x))^{\psi(x)} = \left((1+\alpha(x))^{1/\alpha(x)}\right)^{\alpha(x)\psi(x)}$$
Since in the case under consideration $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}\varphi(x) = 1$, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}\alpha(x) = 0$. There is also an implicit assumption here that $\alpha(x) \ne 0$ for $x$ near $a$. Otherwise the rewriting of $\varphi(x)$ doesn't work. It is unfortunate this was never made explicit, in my opinion.

By applying the two results I mentioned above, we have $$\lim_{x\to a} (1+\alpha(x))^{1/\alpha(x)} = e$$

- If $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}\alpha(x)\psi(x) = b$ for some finite $b$, then by part (1) of the result, $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}\varphi(x)^{\psi(x)} = e^b$$
- If $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}\alpha(x)\psi(x) = \infty$, then $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}\varphi(x)^{\psi(x)} = e^{\infty} = \infty$$
  and if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}\alpha(x)\psi(x) = -\infty$, then $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}\varphi(x)^{\psi(x)} = e^{-\infty} = 0$$
  as an application of part (2).
- If $\alpha(x)\psi(x)$ neither converges nor diverges to $\pm\infty$, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}\varphi(x)^{\psi(x)}$ also will neither converge nor diverge to $\infty$, but this goes beyond what the book is proving.

In all cases, you can say that $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}\varphi(x)^{\psi(x)} = e^{\left(\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}\alpha(x)\psi(x)\right)}$$

Comment: @downmath After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).